# Visualforce component not appearing in Salesforce1

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app

The survey questions stopped displaying with the Winter 17 release. I'm logged in as the same user for the web browser and emulator. I can inspect the source on the emulator, and the code I've shared below is 100% missing. Is there anything that would prevent VF from not appearing in SF1?

Web browser
[image]

Emulator
[image]

vf code

```
        <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="index"/>
        <apex:repeat value="{!ObservationResultInfos}" var="ObservationResultItem" id="repeat" >

            <div class="form-group form-ques" id="ques{!index}">
                <label>{!ObservationResultItem.ObservationQuestion.Question__c}<span style="color:red;margin-left:10px;font-size:12px;display:none;" class="requiredques">(Required)</span></label>
                <div class="slider-control">
                    <div class="range-slider" data-ques="{!index}">
                        <apex:inputHidden id="score" value="{!ObservationResultItem.ObservationScore}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <apex:inputTextarea styleClass="form-control" rows="2" html-placeholder="Comments" value="{!ObservationResultItem.QuestionNote}"/>
            </div>
            <apex:variable value="{!index+1}" var="index"/>
        </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: It might be just a styling issue due to winter 17 .Inspect element the syles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

On the VF controller, a

```
private String survey = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('survey');
```

is used to retrieve which survey is being used to generate the page. After doing some debugging, the web browser returns

> 16:14:37:006 USER_DEBUG [11]|DEBUG|Standard Patient Survey

but SF1 returns

> 16:14:20:067 USER_DEBUG [11]|DEBUG|Standard+Patient+Survey

Doing a

```
survey = survey.replace('+', ' ');
```

in the constructor did the trick. Anyone know why SF1 adds +'s to Apex.Pages params but the browser does not?